# window.onload function is called on page load and also every time I close an overlay

Tags: javascript

I have some JS code that I am trying to debug, and the problem is that the `window.onload` function is being called way more often than I expect it to. Here is my JS code:

```
var trueCountApp = (function(){

    window.onload = function(){openRulesOverlay()};
    document.getElementById("open-rules-overlay-button").onclick = function(){openRulesOverlay()};
    document.getElementById("select-rules-button").onclick = function(){saveRuleSelections()};

    function openRulesOverlay(){
            let blackjackRules;
            if(sessionStorage.blackjackRules){
                blackjackRules = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.blackjackRules);
                for(let i=0; i<blackjackRules.length;i++){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("rule")[i].value = blackjackRules[i];
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("rules_overlay").style.display = "block";
        }

    function saveRuleSelections(){
            let blackjackRules = [];
            let rules = document.getElementsByClassName("rule");
            for(let i=0; i<rules.length;i++){
                blackjackRules.push(rules[i].value);
            }
            let jsonBlackjackRules = JSON.stringify(blackjackRules);
            sessionStorage.setItem("blackjackRules", jsonBlackjackRules);
            document.getElementById("rules_overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
})();
```

There are 2 buttons on my page: one opens an overlay, and the other closes an overlay. I also wanted to run some code a single time when the page is first loaded, and I just used the `openRulesOverlay()` function that I had already written as a placeholder for the code I want to run. What I expected to happen was for the page to load, `openRulesOverlay()` would run once, then the buttons would work as normal from there. However, it seems that the `window.onload` function is running anytime the overlay gets closed. Why is this happening?

Note: I did not include the html code because I didn't think it was relevant to this problem. Let me know if I need to include it.

Comment: Use the debugger to set a breakpoint. Then look at the call stack to see where it's being called from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix in my particular case: the default button type is "submit", so the page would load, the form would open, and then when I pressed a button to close the form, it was essentially reloading the page and opening the form again. Just needed to change button type to "button".